# div content change only jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have that :

> ```
>    <div data-role="page" id="Home"> 
>
>         <div data-role="header" > 
>             <h2 class="header">My app</h2>
>         </div>
>
>         <div data-role="content">
>
>         </div>
>
>         <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
>
>             <div data-role="navbar">
>                 <ul>
>                     <li><a href="partials/home.html" data-icon="home" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li>
>                     <li><a href="partials/about.html" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
>                 </ul>
>             </div>
>
>         </div>
>
>
>     </div>
>
> </body>
> ```

I want when a users click on links le content slide on a div content of for exemple home.html who have just that :

> home

that is possible or not ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There are a lot of variants, for example you can use `jquery.scrollTo`.Take a 
Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2Je7/) how it works.

Also you can use `jquery.animate`, take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8C9xj/19/) that i've created.